# Passing data between different namespaces using Generic list+C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<FieldsInfo>` in two different namespace say `A` & `B` both of them are in different project within same VS solution. I have populated some values for `List<FieldsInfo>` in namespace `B`. I want to pass this list to `List<FieldsInfo>` in namespace `B` to assign value to `ListBox` control. Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can I clarify: do you mean you have `FieldsInfo` defined separately in two namespaces, i.e. `A.FieldsInfo` and `B.FieldsInfo` ? Also, in your example you only make use of `B` - it is not clear where `A` comes into your example.

Comment: so.... where does `A` come into your example?

Comment: A.FieldsInfo will fetch and store values from a datastore in a method which will return List<FieldInfo>. Another method in Namespace B, i would like to access & get the values of A.FieldsInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *nothing* related between `A.FieldsInfo` and `B.FieldsInfo`. The ideal would be to make them only a single type. If that isn't possible, then a lazy compromise is to declare an `IFieldsInfo` somewhere (with the common members), and implement `IFieldsInfo` from both types. One nice thing about this is that implicit interface implementation will kick in, and `partial` classes make it possible to do this even for generated types outside your control:

```
namespace A {
    partial class FieldsInfo : IFieldsInfo {}
}
namespace B {
    partial class FieldsInfo : IFieldsInfo {}
}
```

Now just talk in terms if `IFieldsInfo` instead of either `A.FieldsInfo` or `B.FieldsInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

Two types in different namespaces are *completely* different types as far as both the compiler and the CLR are concerned. The fact that they have the same simple name is irrelevant - and probably confusing in your code, in the long run. You'll need to provide a conversion between the two types - or preferrably, if they represent the same information, only use a single type to start with.

Once you *have* got a conversion (if you still need one) you can either use the [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method:

```
List<Foo> = bars.ConvertAll(bar => Foo.FromBar(bar));
```

or LINQ:

```
List<Foo> = bars.Select(bar => Foo.FromBar(bar))
                .ToList();
```

`ConvertAll` will be slightly more efficient, but LINQ is more flexible if you want to deal with types other than `List<T>`.